# the site has a redirect loop error while visiting site

Tags: django, apache

Am working on a certain django site.
wherever i go to url [1]: http://www.justsaidyes.net  I get an error "This webpage has a redirect loop"
Any one who has encountered similar error before please help
My htaccess code looks like below if it should help you help me

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^justsaidyes\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.justsaidyes\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.justsaidyes\.net\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: A few more details would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you probably have something in your webserver config redirecting in this way (for example) :

```
www.justsaidyes.net -> justsaidyes.net
justsaidyes.net -> www.justsaidyes.net
```

Something like that. If you show more relevant code (maybe some configs?), we could help more ^^.

**EDIT :** After looking at your website with Firebug, it seems you are redirecting `http://www.justsaidyes.net` to ... `http://www.justsaidyes.net`.

**EDIT2 (aftermore code provided) :** You can remove your htaccess file. Django isn't meant to be deployed this way. You have to create a host file in `sites-available` like described here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/.

Then "activate" this website by running `a2ensite NameOfTheFileYouCreated`.

If you want to write redirect rules, you can do it directly in the host. But I don't think you want to do this according to your htaccess, so I guess this would be enough :

```
ServerName justsaidyes.net
ServerAlias www.justsaidyes.net
```

And btw, your htaccess creates a loop, you redirect `http://justsaidyes.net`(3rd line) and `http://www.justsaidyes.net`(4th line) to `http://www.justsaidyes.net`(5th line). Remove the 4th line and you shouldn't have it again.

Comment: my htaccess file looks like this RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^justsaidyes\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.justsaidyes\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.justsaidyes\.net\/" [R=301,L]

Comment: Please edit your answer to post code, I won't read it in a comment like this.

Comment: Edited answer with hopefully more helpful information

Comment: !!! YOU SHOULD BE CAREFUL !!!. You just made a big part your server browsable, including access to your code, all the private keys that are in your settings !!!!!. Solve this and change all the security keys and certificates.

Comment: Judge by yourself : http://www.justsaidyes.net/afteryes/floralfox/floralfox/settings.py. Consider all your security and secret keys as compromised.

Comment: ok thank you raphael just fixed check out..but i cant get to site index still

Comment: Without more information about how you configured your server, we cannot help. Please read the guidelines to redact a proper question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask